# trouble showing id and populating text value with jquery conditional statement

Tags: jquery, html

Ok, I solved something similar the other day, but this is causing me some issues for some reason. Not getting an error at the console log, so I'm not immediately sure what might be missing.

Inserting the HTML above the jQuery code here...and FYI, it is NOT showing me a value of any kind.

```
       <td colspan="5"><select name="acctloc" id="acctloc" required>   
  <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
  <option value="CMI1">CMI-Strategy 1</option>
  <option value="CMI2">CMI-Strategy 2</option>
  <option value="CHE3">CHE-Strategy 3</option>
  <option value="CMI-CRL2">CMI-CRL 2</option>
  <option value="CUST">CHE-Custom</option>
  <option value="Network">Network</option>
  <option value="HELOC">HELOC</option>
  </select>       

<tr id="acct_loc" style="display:none">
 <td align="right"><label for="bank_num_anc">Bank Number ex</label></td>
 <td colspan="5"><input name="bank_num_anc" id="bank_num_anc" type="text" size="8"  ></td></tr>
```

---

```
$(function() {
$("#acctloc").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "CHE" || this.value == "CUST") {
        $('#bank_num_anc').val('CHE')
         $('#acct_loc').css('display', 'table-row');
       alert(" new value for bank num" + $("#bank_num_anc").val());
   }  if (this.value != "CHE" || this.value != "Network" || this.value != "HELOC") {
        $('#bank_num_anc').val()=="CMI";
        $('#acct_loc').css('display', ''table-row'');
        alert(" new value for bank num " + $("#bank_num_anc").val());
    }
     if (this.value == "HELOC") {
        $('#bank_num_anc').val("HELOC");
        $('#acct_loc').css('display', ''table-row'');
        alert(" new value for bank num " + $("#bank_num_anc").val());
    } 
     if (this.value == "Network") {
            $('#bank_num_anc').val('');
            $('#acct_loc').css('display', 'none');
            alert(" new value for bank num " + 

            $("#bank_num_anc").val());
    } 
});
});
```

The id element is not becoming visible, so I'm not even sure if the field value is populating, though I've not viewed the source to confirm. It's doubtful though. Any feedback or direction is appreciated!

And I tried adding block, inline and the above, 'table-row' to no avail. None seems to work. It won't display the element and no value gets assigned.

Comment: 1) `if (this.value != "CHE" || this.value != "Network" || this.value != "HELOC")` looks strange. Do you mean `&&`? 2) `$('#bank_num_anc').val()=="CMI";` looks even stranger. What do you mean?

Comment: That should be correct actually. I think I neglected to add the HTML code, my apologies! Basically I'm wanting to suggest if the dropdown list is NOT any of those values on the select menu, show this other blank text field and assign it that "CMI" value. Meanwhile there are about 4 other vals on the dropdown list that would also assign that value to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly the reason "id element" isn't showing is because

```
$('#acct_loc').css('display', '');
```

is setting the display property to an empty string.

What you want is

```
$('#acct_loc').css('display', 'block[or table, inline, inline-block, etc.]');
```

This of course applies everywhere you were trying `('display', '')`

Comment: Thanks, Pat. I'll change that up accordingly!

Comment: Well, with the edited above, I got it working in IE like a champ. But Chrome? Not so much. Looking into what could be causing the difference there. Doc. get Ekement by Id (the real syntax I mean) allows both to be viewed ok, and that is of course non jquery and non-HTML5 elements. But I'll have to keep exploring as to why Chrome is balking at this syntax above.
Thanks any and all!

Comment: ...what I referenced would work. Here's the JSFiddle link, FWIW.https://jsfiddle.net/bpwebdev/wxo0ors5/8/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. I dumped the "this.val" portion and just specifically assigned a function on the select element to solve this. I think the other entailed either a global solution throughout a form, or just assuming one type of event handler in the mix. I have many!
HTML part

```
   <select name="acctloc" id="acctloc" onChange="funcChg()"; required>
   <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
   <option value="CMI1">CMI-Strategy 1</option>
   <option value="CMI2">CMI-Strategy 2</option> 
   <option value="CHE3">CHE-Strategy 3</option> 
   <option value="CMI-CRL2">CMI-CRL 2</option>
   <option value="CUST">CHE-Custom</option>
   <option value="Network">Network</option>
   <option value="HELOC">HELOC</option>
   </select>
```

---

```
    function funcChg() {
    if ($('#acctloc').val() == "CHE3" || $('#acctloc').val() == "CUST") {
$('#bank_num_anc').val('CHE')
    $('#acct_loc_tr').css('display', '');
$('#networkacct').css('display', 'none');
$('#networkacct').val('');
   }   
   if ($('#acctloc').val() == "CMI-CRL2" || $('#acctloc').val()   == "CMI2"     || $('#acctloc').val() == "CMI1") {
     $('#bank_num_anc').val('CMI')
     $('#acct_loc_tr').css('display', '');
 $('#networkacct').css('display', 'none');
 $('#networkacct').val('');
    }
     if ($('#acctloc').val() == "HELOC") {
     $('#bank_num_anc').val('HELOC');
     $('#acct_loc_tr').css('display', '');
 $('#networkacct').css('display', 'none');
 $('#networkacct').val('');
    } 
     if  ($('#acctloc').val() == "Network")  {
  $('#bank_num_anc').val('');
  $('#acct_loc_tr').css('display', 'none');
  $('#networkacct').css('display', '');
   } 
 else {
 $('#acct_loc_tr').css('display', 'none');
 }
```

;

```
}
```